# Lambda expression question

Tags: .net, linq, lambda

```
string[] fruits = { "apple", "banana", "mango", "orange", 
                      "passionfruit", "grape" };

var query =
    fruits.Select((fruit, index) =>
                      new { index, str = fruit.Substring(0, index) });

foreach (var obj in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
}

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 {index=0, str=}
 {index=1, str=b}
 {index=2, str=ma}
 {index=3, str=ora}
 {index=4, str=pass}
 {index=5, str=grape}
*/
```

Could somebody explain, how "index" is associated here as array index of the elements?

Say, I need a query that instead of first letter returns me the whole object (string in this case) + associated index.

Comment: What do you mean by "Say, I need a query that instead of first letter returns me the whole object (string in this case)."

Comment: I'm assuming that you are either trying to learn the syntax, or actually need something more complex.  Otherwise, I assume that you would use a simple `foreach (var fruit in fruits)` loop and skip the LINQ syntax altogether.

Comment: @Wonko the Sane: I need associate index and corresponding object. Not sure if `foreach` iterates from 0 to *count*, from *count* to 0 or randomly.

Comment: Ok. Of course, you could use `for (int index = 0; index < fruits.Count; index++)`. And loops iterate from 0 to count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index` variable is simply a counter that increments from 0 as you iterate through the list of `fruits`. In this example there is a natural relationship between `index` and the position of `fruit` in `fruits` as you are iterating through `fruits` one element at a time.

I'm not sure about your question regarding access to 'the whole object'. You already have access to this:

```
var query = fruits.Select((fruit, index) => new { index, fruit });
```

`fruit` refers to the current element in `fruits` as you iterate through it.

Answer (score 1):

To return the whole string in each case just modify the query thus:

```
var query =
    fruits.Select((fruit, index) =>
                  new { index, str = fruit });
```

`index` is just that, the array element index.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're asking but try:

```
string[] fruits = { "apple", "banana", "mango", "orange", 
                      "passionfruit", "grape" };

var query =
    fruits.Select((fruit, index) =>
                      new { index, str = fruit });

foreach (var obj in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
}
```

Index is used in an overload of Select to describe the index of the object your lambda is currently iterating over.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how that particular overload of [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) works: *"the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element"*.

If you want the entire string then you can do something like this:

```
var query = fruits.Select((fruit, index) => new { index, str = fruit });
```

Answer (score 1):

The lambda expression populates the first variable name as the item itself, and the second as the index.

So if you have `(fruit,index)` then:

fruit = The data object.

index = The index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question, it is an overload for `Select`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps breaking down what this expression does will help you understand it:

```
fruits.Select((fruit, index) =>
                  new { index, str = fruit.Substring(0, index) });
```

`Select(...)` = With the input, return an output as indicated within.

`(fruit, index)` = Assign the selected fruit to the variable `fruit`, and the index (position in Enumerable) into `index`. As mentioned, this is simply one overload (option) available to you. If you don't care about the index value, simply omit it.

`=>` = return the following value

`new { ... }` = Create an instance of an anonymous type. This type will have two properties: `index`, and `str`. The value of `index` will be the variable `index`. the value of `str` will be the result of the substring on the fruit.

So, if you simply want the fruit, you could rewrite it like so:

```
fruits.Select(fruit => fruit);
```

If you still want the index, with the full name of the fruit:

```
fruits.Select((fruit, index) =>
                  new { index, str = fruit});
```

Select is useful for returning a different set of information from what the input was.

By way of example using a slightly more complex scenario:

For instance, if you had classes like so:

```
public class Customer { 
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name { get; set;}
 public List<Order> Orders { get; set;} 
} 

public class Order { 
 public int Id { get;set;} 
 public double TotalOrderValue { get;set}
}
```

You could use a simple Select statement to return the customer, and the sum of how much that customer has ever ordered:

```
 var customersTotalSpend = customers.Select(
      customer => 
      new { 
            customer, 
            TotalSpend = customer.Orders.Select(order => order.TotalOrderValue).Sum()
           });
```

We could then do something with that TotalSpend value if we wanted, eg getting the 10 biggest spenders:

```
var biggestCustomers = customersTotalSpend.OrderByDescending(customerSpend=> customer.TotalSpend).Take(10);
```

Does that make sense now?